# php soap question: howto create custom namespace

Tags: php, api, soap

I am using php soap. I can't get my soap body to include a custom namespace.
Here is an example of what I want:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF8'?><soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tns:MyCall xmlns:tns="my.sx"><tns:op>getStuff</tns:op><tns:args />
    </tns:MyCall>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I can't get the namespace called tns to appear inside the body, or the elements op and args.

Can anyone suggest how this is done?

My code looks like:

```
$client = CreateSoapClient();

try{
  $result = $client->__soapCall(
   'MyCall',
   array(), // no params
array(
    'uri' => 'urn:Myurn',
    'soapaction' => 'urn:Myurn'
));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your namespace in your WSDL.  It's probably easiest to just use the Zend WSDL autogenerator, which I believe will let you set the namespace.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi benjy,

Thanks for the reply. I may be very close then, because I have wdsl in xml and also a services.xml

Would I create the connection to the server using a local copy of the wdsl by putting the xml in a string ala: 
    <?php
    $client = new SoapClient($wdsl,
    array(
    'trace'=> $trace_on,
    'connection_timeout' => 5,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'exceptions' => 0,
    'location' => $hostname,
    'uri' => 'urn:myURN',
    'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    'use' => SOAP_ENCODED
    ));
    ?>
Or do I put the wdsl file on the server? If so, what to call it?

many thanks

Comment: I would put the WSDL on the server, and then you can just use the WSDL's URI for $wsdl in your code above.  Also, I would strongly recommend setting exceptions to 1 in your options array - makes testing much easier.